# Custom Post type and permalink settings

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

Have Wordpress in the root of the site.  Want the URL structure for pages to be example.com/{page-slug} and for posts to be example.com/academy/{post-slug}. I have my permalinks set to custom with /academy/%postname% as the structure.

This works great.  However, I have a custom post type called definitions.  I would like the definitions URL structure to be example.com/glossary/{definition-slug}.  Currently with the above set up I am getting a URL of example.com/academy/definition/{definition-slug}

Is there a way to exclude custom post types from the post permalink settings?

Here is my custom post definition:

```
function create_posttypes() {
    $labels1 = array(
            'name' => __( 'Definitions' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Definition' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Definitions' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Definition' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Definition' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Definition' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Definition' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Definitions' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'Not Found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not Found in Trash' ),
        );
    $args1 = array(
            'label' => 'Definitions',
            'description' => 'Definitions received',
            'labels' => $labels1,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug', 'definitions'),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'can_export' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'supports' => array('title','thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes')
        );
    register_post_type( 'definitions', $args1 );
}
```

Comment: for the `rewrite` args try this : `["slug" => "glossary", "with_front" => FALSE]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rewrite` parameter to disable the front portion of the URLs (`/academy/` in your case) for custom post types.

```
function create_posttypes() {
    $labels1 = array(
            'name' => __( 'Definitions' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Definition' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Definitions' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View Definition' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Definition' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Definition' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Definition' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Definitions' ),
            'not_found' => __( 'Not Found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not Found in Trash' ),
        );
    $args1 = array(
            'label' => 'Definitions',
            'description' => 'Definitions received',
            'labels' => $labels1,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'glossary',
                'with_front' => false,
             ),
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'can_export' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'supports' => array('title','thumbnail', 'revisions', 'page-attributes')
        );
    register_post_type( 'definitions', $args1 );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Removed the academy.  However I changed the slug from definitions to glossary and it is still showing up with URL of example.com/definitions/{def-slug} instead of example.com/glossary/{def-slug}

Comment: Head over to the permalinks page in the admin. That will reload the permalinks and should fix that issue. (Merely visiting the permalinks page should be enough, but I tend to click the save button anyway.)

Comment: Tried re-saving on permalinks page... no luck

Comment: Hrmm, I tested the code that I posted and verified that it's working (updated the slug to *glossary*, for the record. My bad on missing that). The fact that *definitions* is still appearing in your URL suggests that the permalinks are not being flushed.